# pyodbc keep the column data types while converting to csv

Tags: pandas, pyodbc

I am pulling data using pyodbc and creating a dataframe which is then fed into a csv file. The problem is that a lot of columns have preceeding 0s and they are getting truncated, also some fields have decimal values but they are coming in as integer. Is there anyway to ensure the data being pulled using pyodbc keeps it's datatypes.

I am pulling 128 columns so it's really hard to explicitly state each columns data types. I am going to applying this process to about 50-60 other tables so creating a lookup for each columns data type isn't advisable either. my code is given below:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('driver={SAP HANA};SERVERNODE={'+creds.hana_db+'}', uid=creds.hana_un, pwd=creds.hana_pw)

cursor = conn.cursor()


#ds = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM SAPABAP1.VBAK")

while True:
    dfs = psql.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM SAPABAP1.VBAK ORDER BY VBELN LIMIT %d OFFSET %d" % (chunk, offset) ,conn)

    df.append(dfs)
    offset += chunk
    #print(len(dfs))
    if len(dfs) < chunk: 
        break


final_df = pd.concat(df)
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime()))

#print(final_df.head())
#print(cursor.fetchall())
#print(time.process_time() - start)

conn_sql = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server='+creds.svr+';'
                      'Database='+creds.db+';'
                      'Trusted_Connection=Yes;')


cur_desc = conn_sql.cursor()
cur_desc.execute("Select TOP 1 * from LKP_VBAK")
col = [column[0] for column in cur_desc.description]
cur_desc.close()
    
#print(col)
final_df = final_df[[c for c in final_df.columns if c in col]]
print(final_df['KUNNR'].head())
cur = conn_sql.cursor()
cur.execute("truncate table LKP_VBAK")
cur.commit()
cur.close()
final_df = final_df.reindex(columns=col)
#print(final_df.columns)
print("Table Truncated")
final_df.to_csv(creds.path+'output.csv', sep =',', na_rep ='',encoding = 'utf-8-sig', index = False)
curr_in = conn_sql.cursor()
print("inserting")
curr_in.execute("""BULK INSERT LKP_VBAK FROM 'path.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR =',', CHECK_CONSTRAINTS, ROWTERMINATOR ='\n', MAXERRORS = 999, ERRORFILE = 'path\\VBAK_log');""")
conn_sql.commit()
```

I need to convert it to a csv as I am using Bulk insert to push the data into a SQL Server. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/5gMGARLC) works fine for me. Are you sure it's not the consuming application that is implicitly converting strings like `000123` to integer, thereby stripping the leading zeros? (Excel is notorious for that.)

Comment: @GordThompson the consuming application is a pyodbc execution of a bulk insert into sql server. Gives errors on different columns at different rows saying `mismatch and character varying` . I have added the complete code.

Comment: Do you have any better luck if you use something like `df.to_csv(csv_path, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, index=False)` ?